# Convert facebook date into timestamp format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

I get birthday from facebook in this format

```
"12/09/1993"
```

But in timestamp format is `yyyy/mm/dd` How I convert facebook data into this with min lines of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Time.parse("12/09/1993").strftime("%Y/%m/%d")
#=> "1993/09/12"
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you can see different sort of combinations:

```
 require 'date'

 date = "01/07/2016 09:17AM"
 DateTime.parse(date).strftime("%A, %b %d")
 #=> Friday, Jul 01

 DateTime.parse(date).strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
 #=> 07/01/2016

 DateTime.parse(date).strftime("%m-%e-%y %H:%M")
 #=> 07- 1-16 09:17

 DateTime.parse(date).strftime("%b %e")
 #=> Jul  1

 DateTime.parse(date).strftime("%l:%M %p")
 #=>  9:17 AM

 DateTime.parse(date).strftime("%B %Y")
 #=> July 2016
 DateTime.parse(date).strftime("%b %d, %Y")
 #=> Jul 01, 2016
 DateTime.parse(date).strftime("%a, %e %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z")
 #=> Fri,  1 Jul 2016 09:17:00 +0200
 DateTime.parse(date).strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%l:%M:%S%z")
 #=> 2016-07-01T 9:17:00+0200
 DateTime.parse(date).strftime("%I:%M:%S %p")
 #=> 09:17:00 AM
 DateTime.parse(date).strftime("%H:%M:%S")
 #=> 09:17:00
 DateTime.parse(date).strftime("%e %b %Y %H:%M:%S%p")
 #=>  1 Jul 2016 09:17:00AM
 DateTime.parse(date).strftime("%d.%m.%y")
 #=> 01.07.16
 DateTime.parse(date).strftime("%A, %d %b %Y %l:%M %p")
 #=> Friday, 01 Jul 2016  9:17 AM
```

Even more combinations here:  http://www.foragoodstrftime.com/

Answer (score 1):

Use [strftime](http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime)

```
date = "12/09/1993".to_date # => Sun, 12 Sep 1993
date.strftime("%Y/%m/%d") # => "1993/09/12"
```